# Android: can't share on google+ text and images together

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm use this code to share on google+:

```
    ShareCompat.IntentBuilder builder = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity);
    builder.setType("text/plain");
    builder.setText(text);
    if (imageURI != null) {
        builder.setStream(imageURI)
               .setType("image/png");
    }

    Intent shareIntent = builder.getIntent()
            .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
    activity.startActivity(shareIntent);
```

And if there is an image - it share image without text, if there is no image - it share text successfully. 
How can I post text and images together?

Comment: When you say you are "sharing successfully," what exactly do you mean by that? Are you incorporating the Google+ Share button in your app? Or are you trying to post to the Google+ stream directly? Currently, the latter is not allowed, as the Google+ API does not have write access. Are you "sharing" by writing moments?

Comment: When I'm using this code - it starts Google+ app, where I pass parameters through intent. And if I pass only text - it display this text, if I pass image stream - it display attached image, but when I try to pass them both - it's display only image

Comment: Have you tried creating your builder like this: `PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(activity);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been trying to solve this today and I think I got it - I hope you have solved it in the meantime, but still somebody else may find this useful.

```
File f = new File(your_file_path);
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png"); //or /jpeg or whatever
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, f.getAbsolutePath());
                Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("image/png");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "blahblah");
                intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
                startActivity(intent);
```

I think the problem with your code might be that you "override" the text type with the image. I haven't used IntentBuilders, though, so feel free to correct me on that.